# How to add tuple value

Tags: python

Am trying to add the values in my tuple to get the total figure with the below code

```
Black = (("Hans","100"),("Frank","20.5"))

for v in Black:
    print(v[1])
    print (v[1]+v[1])
```

But when i do it this way it concatenate the values like 100100 and not total figure of the values

Comment: Those numbers are of type str.  So when you try to "add" strings they concatenate together.  You need to turn them into floats before adding them.

Comment: `for name, value in Black: print(name) print(2*float(value))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Take the quotes off the values in the tuple:

```
Black = (("Hans",100),("Frank",20.5))
for v in Black:
       print(v[1])
       print (v[1]+v[1])
```

2) Convert the strings to float during the loop:

```
Black = (("Hans","100"),("Frank","20.5"))
for v in Black:
       print(v[1])
       print (float(v[1])+float(v[1]))
```

3) If your goal is the sum all the [1] index values in your list of lists:

```
Black = (("Hans",100),("Frank",20.5))
sum([x[1] for x in Black])
```

Comment: It doesn't give total of 100+20.5

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
Black = (("Hans","100"),("Frank","20.5"))

res = sum(float(num) for name, num in Black)
# 120.5
```

Alternative method using `zip`:

```
res = sum(map(float, list(zip(*Black))[1]))
# 120.5
```